# I'm having more trouble than I thought with a random equation generator in Visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to do an assignment in my VB book, Programming challenge 7. Integer Math Tutor.  I'm mostly trying to figure out how to use a loop with the code.

Edit: The rabtnSubt, rabtnMulti, and rabtnDivi are all being unused.  Yes I know they're not commented out but all they do is generate a random number.

The random number generator is not global because when ever I wanted a random number, both randNumb1 and randNumb2 would be exactly the same.

And to give an Idea of what this program is meant to do, here is the assignment: "Create an application that uses random integers to test the user’s knowledge of arithmetic. Let the user choose from addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. The integers used in the problems should range from 20 to 120. When giving feedback, use color to differentiate between a correct answer response, versus an incorrect answer response. Also check for non-integer input. Preparing division problems requires special consideration because the quotient must be an integer. Therefore, you can use a loop to generate new random values for the second operand until you find one that divides the first operand evenly. Use the Mod operator to verify that the integer division remainder is zero."

I would give more info on the error I get with the txtBox but it's just "System.InvalidCastException: "

**Buttons**

- Check Answer
- Next Problem

**Radio Buttons**

- Add
- Subtract
- Multiply
- Divide

**Input**

- Textbox (Answer)

**Output**

- Question / Equation
- Response(good job, wrong answer)

Here's whats inside my form class. I can't figure out if the check answer button is actually working correctly and that `If Not Integer` statement is there because when I used `inputNumb = txtInputNumb.Text` I would get an error.

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Dim rand As Random
    Dim ranNumb1, ranNumb2, inputNumb, sumNumb As Integer

    Private Sub rabtnAdd_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rabtnAdd.CheckedChanged
        Do
            ' Output Random Number
            rand = New Random
            ranNumb1 = rand.Next(20, 121)
            ranNumb2 = rand.Next(20, 121)
            lblQuestion.Text = ranNumb1 & (" + ") & ranNumb2 & (" = ")

            sumNumb = ranNumb1 = ranNumb2

            If Not Integer.TryParse(txtInputNumb.Text, inputNumb) Then
                lblTalkBack.Text = ("Error in box B, Interger Only.")
                Exit Sub
            End If

            lblTalkBack.Text = sumNumb
        Loop
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCheck_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheck.Click
        If inputNumb = sumNumb Then
            lblTest.Text = ("good")
        Else
            lblTest.Text = ("bad")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub rabtnSubt_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rabtnSubt.CheckedChanged
        rand = New Random
        ranNumb1 = rand.Next(20, 121)
        ranNumb2 = rand.Next(20, 121)
        lblQuestion.Text = ranNumb1 & (" - ") & ranNumb2 & (" = ")

        lblTest.Text = ("test2")
    End Sub

    Private Sub rabtnMulti_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rabtnMulti.CheckedChanged
        rand = New Random
        ranNumb1 = rand.Next(20, 121)
        ranNumb2 = rand.Next(20, 121)
        lblQuestion.Text = ranNumb1 & (" * ") & ranNumb2 & (" = ")

        lblTest.Text = ("test3")
    End Sub

    Private Sub rabtnDivi_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rabtnDivi.CheckedChanged
        rand = New Random
        ranNumb1 = rand.Next(20, 121)
        ranNumb2 = rand.Next(20, 121)
        lblQuestion.Text = ranNumb1 & (" / ") & ranNumb2 & (" = ")

        lblTest.Text = ("test4")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your Question is better than most first attempts that get posted here, but it's still lacking what output you are getting and how it differs from what you'd expect, could you edit the question to add that information? `I can't figure out if the check answer button is actually working correctly ` unfortunately doesn't actually tell us much about what's wrong.

Comment: Are you actually debugging your code, i.e. setting a breakpoint, stepping through the code line by line and examining the state at each step?  That's how you determine whether code is doing what it is supposed to.  *"I would get an error"*.  If you were to provide details then we might be able to determine the cause and the solution.

Comment: On an unrelated note, don't keep creating new `Random` objects all the time. The idea is that you just create one and then use it every time.  Change `Dim rand As Random` to `Dim rand As New Random` and never set that variable again.

Comment: `sumNumb = ranNumb1 = ranNumb2` What is this line supposed to be doing?

Comment: You don't need that loop, it's not a Console application. Imitate the codes of the other check boxes. What about the Division? not always returns integer values. Also, It's good idea to rename the `sumNumb` to for example `result` since it can be a `sum`, `difference`, `product`, or `quotient`. Good luck.

Comment: @Mary Thanks for pointing that out it's supposed to be, ranNumb1 + ranNumb2.

Comment: @JQSOFT What do you mean I don't need a loop if it's not a console app?

Comment: I mean the code in `rabtnAdd` should be just like the code in the other radio buttons except doing the addition operation. You need to remove the loop and to move the `If Not Integer.TryParse ...` to the `btnCheck_Click`. event. If it returns `True` then proceed otherwise show the error message and `return`.

Comment: Incidentally, for the division *a* / *b* = *c*, it's better to generate *b* and *c* then calculate *a* for the question. That way you know the result will always be an integer.

Answer (score 1):

First, when the checked property of an radio button changes another button also changes. When you click one another one becomes unchecked. So you will be triggering two of your event procedures.

There are several ways to handle this problem. One is to check in each event procedure if the radio button is checked before allowing the code to run. Another is to combine code into a single event procedure that Handles all 4 of the radio buttons. See `Private Sub OperationButtons_CheckedChanged`. Notice that this has a all 4 buttons listed in the Handles clause.

Next we need to find out which radio button is checked. This is done with a bit of Linq. It considers the Controls collection of the form and only looks at the RadioButton class. Only one can be checked at a time so .FirstOrDefault and the one we want is where Checked = True.

When the user clicks Check we need to validate that they have entered a number. I switched the type to Double because division can produce a number that is not an Integer.

```vb
Private Rand As New Random
Private ranNumb1, ranNumb2 As Integer
Private CorrectAnswer, UsersAnswer As Double

Private Sub MathQuiz_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MessageBox.Show("Please select Add, Subtract, Multiply or Divide.")
End Sub

Private Sub btnCheck_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheck.Click

    If Not Double.TryParse(txtAnswer.Text, UsersAnswer) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number")
        Return
    End If

    If UsersAnswer = CorrectAnswer Then
        lblResponse.Text = "good"
    Else
        lblResponse.Text = "bad"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub OperationButtons_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rabtnAdd.CheckedChanged, rabtnSubt.CheckedChanged, rabtnMulti.CheckedChanged, rabtnDivi.CheckedChanged
    Dim rButton As RadioButton = Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton).FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.Checked = True)
    Dim MathOperator As String = ""
    ranNumb1 = Rand.Next(20, 121)
    ranNumb2 = Rand.Next(20, 121)
    Select Case rButton.Name
        Case "rabtnAdd"
            MathOperator = "+"
            CorrectAnswer = ranNumb1 + ranNumb2
        Case "rabtnSubt"
            MathOperator = "-"
            CorrectAnswer = ranNumb1 - ranNumb2
        Case "rabtnMulti"
            MathOperator = "*"
            CorrectAnswer = ranNumb1 * ranNumb2
        Case "rabtnDivi"
            MathOperator = "/"
            CorrectAnswer = ranNumb1 / ranNumb2
    End Select
    lblQuestion.Text = $"{ranNumb1} {MathOperator} {ranNumb2} = ?"

End Sub

Private Sub btnNextQuestion_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNextQuestion.Click
    lblQuestion.Text = ""
    lblResponse.Text = ""
    txtAnswer.Text = ""
    rabtnAdd.Checked = False
    rabtnSubt.Checked = False
    rabtnMulti.Checked = False
    rabtnDivi.Checked = False
    MessageBox.Show("Please select Add, Subtract, Multiply or Divide.")
End Sub
```